# Can't get property value from JSON file

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get the "Stockcode" value from this Json file, I'm trying to do it with python using this code:

```
import json     
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
     datastore = json.load(f)

print datastore["Bundles"]["Products"][1]["Stockcode"]
```

Do you have an idea why this isn't working ? I'm getting an Out of index error.
This is the JSON file:

```js
{
    "Bundles": [
        {
            "Products": [
                {
                    "Stockcode": 1
                }],
                
             "Products": [
                {
                    "Stockcode": 2
                }]
                
        }]
        
}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Please give a [mre] of the structure you're working with.

Comment: Your json code does not encode a valid dict - it has duplicate keys. The produced dict will only have one "product", thus the out of index error.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen what could be done to access duplicated keys then ?

Comment: "Bundles" is an array of objects. You are trying to access it as a dictionary. Your code should be `datastore["Bundles"][0]["Products"][0]["Stockcode"]`, but it also looks like your JSON has some formatting issues

Comment: `Bundles` is a list not a dict so you can access its items via an integer index.

Comment: As others already wrote, "Bundles" is a list that contains a dict, but this dict has duplicate keys and is therefore not valid. Do you generate the json yourself, or do you get it from somewhere else?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen From a client, the keys should stay duplicated can't do anything about it

Comment: On a second glance, this is really invalid JSON, I didn't notice that "Products": is also a list, but the brackets to not match. If this is really the JSON you get, it's broken.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Maybe I did a mistake shorting it, because it is a long file, I left only 2 properties

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I forgot to close a ']' when I copied it, but still the same file

Comment: Well, back to duplicate keys in the dict now... I don't think you can get both "Products" using `json.load`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the JSON and proposing an example access ...

```
datastore = \
{
   "Bundles":[
      {
         "Products":[
            {
               "Stockcode":1
            },
            {
               "Stockcode":2
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

print(datastore["Bundles"][0]["Products"][1]["Stockcode"])
```

Gives `2`

Comment: Thanks, but this file should have duplicated keys (not mine) Is there anyway to select second products of bundles the same way it is ?

Comment: I used exactly your data, not sure what else you are referring to

Comment: I have duplicated "products", you set 2 different properties on 1 "products"

Comment: Ah ok @aliouawalid .. then it's not a correct JSON at all, this is unlikely to work. Maybe manipulate the raw file to have Bundles an array of arrays